# How to get array value to variable from string in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to get the value of multi-dimensional array in PHP that is a value of a variable.

The multi-dimensional array has value 12345

```
$data_array['result']['21']['rich_snippet']['top']['detected_extensions']['reviews'] = "12345";
```

The array and index(es) are stored as value of a variable $x

```
$x = "data_array['organic_results']['21']['rich_snippet']['top']['detected_extensions']['reviews'] ";
```

I expect that  `echo $$x;` will return the value of the array `12345`, but i get `null`

Comment: What is the question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to get an array value from a string.

It can be implemented like this:

```
$data_array['result']['21']['rich_snippet']['top']['detected_extensions']['reviews'] = "12345";
    
$string = "data_array['result']['21']['rich_snippet']['top']['detected_extensions']['reviews']";
    
//Here we escape the $ symbol and substitute our string, then we execute the string through the eval function
$value = eval("return \${$string};"); 
    
echo $value;
```

---

**Note**

The [eval](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.eval.php) function is considered very **dangerous**, if you receive a string from the user, then you should not trust the data.

---

I also want to emphasize that if you use hosting services, then the function may not be available, since it is usually disabled for security reasons.

Comment: this data comes from database not from user. Thank you Harvi